# drawer indicator with ActionBar compat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-actionbar-compat

I have an application that is using the ActionBarCompat library as well as the [NavigationDrawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) support library.

I have managed to set up [ActionBarDrawerToggle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) to get the drawer indicator on ICS+ devices, but it doesn't automatically enable it on Gingerbread devices with the ActionbarCompat.

Does anybody know of a way, or what changes I would need to make to the ActionBarCompat to enable the drawer indicator for those devices?

Comment: I also want to use ActionBarCompat in my project. Apparently, they announced an ActionBarCompat library to be released soon. They also mentioned that is what the Google I/O app is using. Sadly, there are no news about it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by manually adding an image view as the first item in the ActionBarCompat, by modifying the construction of the compatibility bar in the library itself.

I believe the particular class in question is `ActionBarHelperBase.java`

Once this is in place, I animate it (similar to the real one) by translating the image in drawer open/close callbacks.

I say "similar" because the difference with my "hack" is that it will not animate until the drawer has finished opening/closing whereas the real one opens/closes WHILE the drawer is opening closing. it is a minor difference and doesn't/shouldn't cause too much issue.

There is not need to do conditional checking within the class because the code is only ever called for "compatible" ActionBars (i.e. pre-honeycomb).